# Wifi connection problem acer aspire E5-573-587Q

Tags: networking, drivers, ethernet, acer

I have bought a acer Aspire laptop. I have installed Ubuntu.
I am unable to connect to internet . There are no WiFi signal available in laptop.

The output of `iwconfig`:

```
eth0 no wireless extensions
lo no wireless extensions
```

The output of `sudo lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev e4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros Device 0042 (rev 30)
```

The output of `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2`:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0042] (rev 30)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc Device [11ad:0806]
```

The output of `dmesg | grep ath`:

```
[    3.400389] Loaded X.509 cert 'Magrathea: Glacier signing key: 00a5a65759de474bc5c43120880c1b94a539f431'
[ 7950.375244]  [<ffffffff810676bd>] warn_slowpath_common+0x7d/0xa0
[ 7950.375247]  [<ffffffff8106772c>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x4c/0x50
```

Comment: @KarlRichter i have posted the ouput of  `sudo lspci`

Comment: We would also like to see: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` and also: `dmesg | grep ath` Welcome to askubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 thanks, i have posted the output of above two commands.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "options ath10k_core skip_otp=y" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k_core.conf

# Download the backport
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2015/11/20/backports-20151120.tar.gz

# Extract it
tar zxvf backports-20151120.tar.gz

# cd to the directory, compile and install it. The commands 'make' and 'make install' will take some time to finish
cd backports-20151120
make defconfig-wifi
make
sudo make install

# Download the firmware for the WiFi card
git clone https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware.git

# Copy the firmware to appropriate locations. 
sudo cp -r ath10k-firmware/QCA9377 /lib/firmware/ath10k/
sudo cp /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin_WLAN.TF.1.0-00267-1 /lib/firmware/ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin
```